# Как исправить ошибку в IntellijIDEA при обращении к файлу Cargo.toml после установки плагина Rust?

Tags: intellij-idea, плагин, rust

Ошибка:

```
Language Language: TOML doesn't participate in view provider SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://D:/CODE/Rust/Test/Cargo.toml, content=VirtualFileContent{size=88}}: [Language: TOML]

java.lang.AssertionError: Language Language: TOML doesn't participate in view provider SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://D:/CODE/Rust/Test/Cargo.toml, content=VirtualFileContent{size=88}}: [Language: TOML]
at com.intellij.extapi.psi.PsiFileBase.findLanguage(PsiFileBase.java:58)
at com.intellij.extapi.psi.PsiFileBase.<init>(PsiFileBase.java:40)
at org.toml.lang.core.psi.TomlFile.<init>(TomlFile.kt:9)
at org.toml.lang.core.parser.TomlParserDefinition.createFile(TomlParserDefinition.kt:24)
at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.createFile(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:410)
at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.createFile(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:351)
at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.createFile(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:329)
at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.getPsiInner(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:174)
at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.getPsi(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:158)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.FileManagerImpl.findFile(FileManagerImpl.java:410)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiManagerImpl.findFile(PsiManagerImpl.java:184)
at com.intellij.packageDependencies.ui.FileNode.getFile(FileNode.java:130)
at com.intellij.packageDependencies.ui.FileNode.getPsiElement(FileNode.java:85)
at com.intellij.ide.scopeView.ScopeTreeViewPanel$1.getFileColorFor(ScopeTreeViewPanel.java:124)
at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree.paintFileColorGutter(Tree.java:341)
at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree.paintComponent(Tree.java:318)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree.paint(Tree.java:232)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
at com.intellij.ui.components.JBViewport.paint(JBViewport.java:122)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5219)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1572)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1495)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1265)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5167)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4978)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:824)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:807)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:782)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:731)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(RepaintManager.java:64)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1720)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Ошибка появилась после установки плагина Rust. Сам плагин работает. Программы компилируются и запускаются. Работает Cargo.

Comment: С таким вопросом лучше обратиться к автору плагина или разработчикам IntellijIDEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась настройкой соответствия расширений файлов. В Idea расширение .toml рассматривалось как расширение проекта и файла одновременно. Настройка на соответствие выполняется через опцию File Types